# ArcGIS JS API - Masking a Layer - Changing the tilelayer source?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, masking, tile-layer

I am trying to reproduce and modify the mask effect found in this example from the ArcGIS JS API:

[Masking effect using a custom layer view](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/custom-lv-masking/index.html)

There is a lot of fancy footwork to modify the underlying tile layer and apply the mask effect based on a [polygon feature layer](https://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Countries_(Generalized)/FeatureServer/0).  One thing I cannot seem to understand is how the underlying tile set is being called, and how I can change it.  It seems that this example is using the esri terrain / world imagery tile set, but I don't see where that is being referenced.  I want to try to recreate this mask effect using a different layer underneath, but I can't seem to find where I might reference a different layer to use underneath the mask.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about the basemap. The example uses ESRI World Imagery service, and it is set on map creation,

```
const map = new Map({
  basemap: "satellite", // <- here
  layers: [layer]
});
```

[ArcGIS API - Map basemap](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-Map.html#basemap)

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helps you!!